# How do I visualize monthly data?

Tags: matplotlib, data-visualization, visualization, seaborn

How do I visualize monthly data in the format shown below? What these 2 charts called?

[image]

As suggested in the comment, this is possible using heatmap. But I am not able to visualize this data in that format.

```
import pandas as pd
import fix_yahoo_finance as yf

start_date = '2015-01-01'
end_date = '2018-12-01'
df=yf.download('TCS.NS', start_date, end_date)
df['year'] = df.index.year
df['month'] = df.index.month
df = df.reset_index()

df = df[['year', 'month', 'Close']]
```

Comment: The right one is sort of heat map (accessible as `heatmap` in seaborn and `imshow` in matplotlib for example) and the left one is a simple 1d line plot with a fill option where the area under the curve is filled with light red color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# generate fake data
start_date = '2015-01-01'
end_date = '2018-12-01'
idx = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':-2+2*np.random.random(size=(len(idx),))}, index=idx)

# reformat dataframe in preparation of the heatmap
monthly = df.resample('M').mean()
monthly['month'] = monthly.index.month
monthly['year'] = monthly.index.year
pv = monthly.pivot("month", "year", "value")

# plot the heatmap
sns.heatmap(pv)
```

[image]